# LINQ inner join 4 tables (convert SQL to C# LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq

**Hello. I am trying to join 4 tables:**

tStore(StoreID, Store_Name)

tSection(SectionID, Section_Name)

tSectionSqft(SectionSqftID, StoreID, SectionID,Sqft)

tSectionForwardSelling(SectionForwardSellingID, StoreID, SectionID, Amount, Date)

**I want the query to give me results:**

Store_Name, Section_Name, Sqft, Amount

I need to convert this SQL query to C# LINQ:

```
SELECT
    tStore.Store_Name, 
    tSection.Section_Name,  
    tSectionSqft.Sqft,  
    tSectionForwardSelling.Amount
FROM tSection  
INNER JOIN tSectionForwardSelling 
      ON tSection.SectionID = tSectionForwardSelling.SectionID 
INNER JOIN tSectionSqft 
      ON tSection.SectionID = tSectionSqft.SectionID 
INNER JOIN tStore 
      ON tSectionForwardSelling.StoreID = tStore.StoreID 
         AND tSectionSqft.StoreID = tStore.StoreID
```

I tried on my own but each time LINQ gives me wrong results.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: What did you try already, and what wrong results did you see?

Comment: Yes. It is Asp.net MVC project.

Answer (score 2):

```
var queryResult = from a in tSection
            join b in tSectionForwardSelling on a.SectionID equals b.SectionID 
            join c in tSectionSqft on a.SectionID equals c.SectionID
            join d in tStore on new { u1 = b.SectionID , u2 = c.SectionID } equals new { u1 = d.SectionID , u2 = d.SectionID }
            select new { d.Store_Name, a.Section_Name, c.Sqft, b.Amount };
```

Comment: www.dropbox.com/s/qbb7qz3shbkuot2/pic.png?dl=0                   It should work

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwgF9RnNTDDEVGJMMTdmMlh5VzA/view?usp=sharing

Link from google drive

Comment: Answer has updated. If work please mark it as answer. It will helpful for other.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwgF9RnNTDDEVkZwQXdkMU5xcGpESGJnLWpiTGEydU4yN2RR/view?usp=sharing

still an error

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this (just a snippet):

```
var result = from s in tSection join  ss in tSectionForwardSelling on s.SectionId equals ss.sectionID
        join sq in tSectionSqft on s.SectonId equals sq.SectionID
        join st in stores on ......
        select new {field1 = s.Field1
                    field2 = sq.FieldName,...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class RetrieveData
{
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
    public string SectionName { get; set; }
    public int Sqft { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}

public void Method(tStore store)
{
    // Store_Name, Section_Name, Sqft, Amount

    var list = from se in Context.Sections
               join fs in tSectionForwardSelling on se.SectionID equals fs.SectionID 
               join sqft in tSectionSqft on se.SectionID equals sqft.SectionID
               join st in tStore on new { u1 = fs.StoreID , u2 = st.StoreID } equals new { u1 = sqft.StoreID , u2 = st.StoreID }
               select new RetrieveData() {
                   StoreName = st.Store_Name,
                   SectionName = se.Section_Name,
                   Sqft = sqft.Sqft,
                   Amount = fs.Amount };
}
```

I want to give part credit of the `join` to @Nazmul.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwgF9RnNTDDEa0FTNloxWjVGaGxuRWRWT1diNGN2RTdwSzBB/view?usp=sharing

tStore has a many to many with tSection through bridge tables tSectionSqft and tSectioForwardSelling

Comment: These are my models:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwgF9RnNTDDEV3ZGS2xRamo2OFhsS05pQ3oyck9UNkx0MFMw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I wish it was just a simple LINQ query

Comment: Ok. But what do you want to retrieve on the query? Because you don't need to do a `join` at all if you have **Navigation Properties**.

Comment: I want to retrieve Store_Name, Section_Name, Sqft, Amount. This data is in 4 tables. I need to join them to get it. I want to use just a LINQ.